# Powershell Copy-Item, from remote PC to remote PC

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a folder and subfolders from a server to a PC (both remotely).

```
$source='\\\server1\folder\\*'
$destination='\\\PC1\c$\temp\folder'
copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -recurse -force
```

This produces an error if I do it once, but if I run the same command again, it completes without error

Error is multiple instances of:

```
copy-item : container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.
%
%
%
     + categoryinfo    : Invalidargument: (\\server1\folder:string) [copy-item] PSargumentexception
    +FullyQualifiedErrrId : CopyContainerItemToLeafError,Microsoft.powershell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Like I said it completes without error the second time I run the command.  What am I doing wrong that makes the error on the first run?

Comment: Try the command with `$source='\\server1\folder'` just like that rather than the asterisk and see what happens. You could also try `Copy-Item  -Recurse -Filter *.*  -path $source -destination $destination -Force` and use `-Filter` for the wildcard string pattern, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the source variable like this **`$source='\\server1\folder'`** and exclude the asterisk (**`*`**) from there as it is in the example provided. You don't need to escape the backslash (**`\`**) characters with an additional backslash so omit the additional backslashes in the UNC paths too.

**Consider Using**

```
$source='\\server1\folder'
$destination='\\PC1\c$\temp\folder'
Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.* -path $source -destination $destination -Force
```

***<sup>Note:</sup>*** <sup>Use **`-Filter`** for the wildcard string pattern, etc.</sup>

---

### Further Resources

- [**Copy-Item**](http://ss64.com/ps/copy-item.html)